# Go - formFile for multiple files

Tags: forms, http, go

The formFile function works perfectly but [in the docs](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormFile) it´s said that the "FormFile returns the first file for the provided form key". Is there a way of obtaining the several files that an html form with an input like:

```
<input type="file" name="myfiles" multiple="multiple">
```

might return?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

FormFile is a convenience function. You can manually parse and find the files you are looking for in the MultipartForm.

```
req.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20) // 32MB is the default used by FormFile
fhs := req.MultipartForm.File["myfiles"]
for _, fh := range fhs {
    f, err := fh.Open()
    // f is one of the files
}
```